# even symmetry of magnitude and odd symmetry of phase

Tags: fourier, transform

I'll appreciate it if any of you guys could help me with this question:
Suppose that x(t) is a real signal, prove that the magnitude of its Fourier transform has even symmetry and its phase has odd symmetry.
Thanks.

Comment: That is a typical homework assignment, so we can't provide a solution. However, if you show what you've tried and where you're stuck you might get some help.